# Can't install any update and packages ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-installation

I am using ubuntu 14.10. I am trying to install all updates, but it's show me the following result:

> The package system is broken
>
> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
>   Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: `apt-get install -f`

Details:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gcc-4.9-multilib: Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is installed
                  Depends: gcc-4.9 (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is installed
                  Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
                  Depends: lib32gcc-4.9-dev (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is installed
                  Depends: libx32gcc-4.9-dev (= 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is installed
libc6-dev-x32: Depends: libc6-x32 (= 2.19-10ubuntu2.3) but 2.19-10ubuntu2.3 is installed
               Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-10ubuntu2.3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libc6-dev (= 2.19-10ubuntu2.3) but 2.19-10ubuntu2.3 is installed
```

Then I removed the third party repositories and run the command in terminal `sudo apt-get -f install`. But after all I got the following error:

```
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-10ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/fpu_control.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-10ubuntu2.3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-10ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, now I need the person who can fix the problem. Great pleasure if you can help me to get out this problem. Please...

Comment: What third party repositories did you have? How did you remove them?

Comment: @ xangua - I found third party repositories in my update manager settings and there have a option to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "software & updates",  then select the "other software" panel; check all the boxes.  After that just follow the prompts. Finally, open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```